# Cant make a function work for a hamburger icon to open a hidden div?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I previously had the following function working on an earlier build but after re-designing my headers layout with flexbox I can no longer get the function to toggle class the div (using the hamburger icon to view the responsive-nav menu) to work?

```js
$(window).scroll({
    previousTop: 0
  },
  function() {
    var currentTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (currentTop < this.previousTop) {
      $(".wrapper").show(300);
    } else if (!$('#hamburger').hasClass('open')) {
      $(".wrapper").hide(300);
    }
    this.previousTop = currentTop;
  });

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#hamburger').click(function() {
    var clicks = $(this).data('clicks');
    if (clicks) {
      $('.responsive-nav').toggleClass('responsive-nav-view');
    } else {
      $('.responsive-nav').toggleClass('responsive-nav-view');
    }
    $(this).data("clicks", !clicks);
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#hamburger').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('open');
  });
});
```

```css
/*
 Theme Name: HTML5 Blank
 Theme URI: http://html5blank.com
 Description: HTML5 Blank WordPress Theme
 Version: 1.4.3
 Author: Todd Motto (@toddmotto)
 Author URI: http://toddmotto.com
 Tags: Blank, HTML5, CSS3

 License: MIT
 License URI: http://opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
*/

/*------------------------------------*\
    MAIN
\*------------------------------------*/

/* global box-sizing */
*,
*:after,
*:before {
 -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
 box-sizing:border-box;
 -webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;
 font-smoothing:antialiased;
 text-rendering:optimizeLegibility;
}
/* html element 62.5% font-size for REM use */
html {
 font-size:62.5%;
}
body {
 font:300 11px/1.4 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 color:#444;
        
}
/* clear */
.clear:before,
.clear:after {
    content:' ';
    display:table;
}

.clear:after {
    clear:both;
}
.clear {
    *zoom:1;
}
img {
 max-width:100%;
 vertical-align:bottom;
}
a {
 color:#444;
 text-decoration:none;
}
a:hover {
 color:#444;
}
a:focus {
 outline:0;
}
a:hover,
a:active {
 outline:0;
}
input:focus {
 outline:0;
 border:1px solid #04A4CC;
}

/*------------------------------------*\
    STRUCTURE
\*------------------------------------*/

/* container all content ends in footer */

#container {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 71px;
    height: 100%;
    clear: both;
    z-index: 0;
        
}

@media (max-width: 450px){
    
    #container {
        display: flex;
        width: 100%;
        margin-top: 50px;
        height: 2000px;
        z-index: 0;
    }
}

/* header */

/* ==== WRAPPER FOR HEADER START ==== */

.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    height: 80px;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #eee;
            
}

.wrapper.hidden {
    transform: translate3d(0,-100%,0);
}

/* ==== WRAPPER FOR HEADER @ MEDIA MAX WIDTH 450 PX ==== */



@media (max-width: 899px){
    
    .wrapper {
        display: flex;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 0;
        height: 70px;
        z-index: 1;
    }
}

/* ==== WRAPPER FOR HEADER END ==== */

/* ===== SOCIAL MEDIA MENU START ==== */

/* ===== SOCIAL MENU MAX WIDTH 899 PX ==== */

@media only screen and (max-width: 899px){

    .socials {
        width: 20%;
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        align-items: center;
        border-left: 2px solid #eee;
        margin-right: 2.5%;
        padding-left: 2.5%;
        
        
    }

    .socials ul li {
        height: 35px;
        width: 35px;
        
    }

    .socials ul {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        list-style: none;
        align-items: center;
        padding: 0;
        width: 100%;
        justify-content: space-around;
                
    }

    .socials li img {
        max-height: 35px;
    }
}

/* ===== SOCIAL MENU MAX WIDTH 899 PX END ==== */

@media only screen and (min-width: 900px) {

    .socials {
        width: 17.5%;
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        align-items: center;
        border-left: 2px solid #eee;
        margin-right: 2.5%;
        padding-left: 2.5%;
        
        
    }

    .socials ul li {
        height: 40px;
        width: 40px;
        
    }

    .socials ul {
        display: flex;
        list-style: none;
        align-items: center;
        padding: 0;
        width: 100%;
        justify-content: space-around;
                
    }

    .socials li img {
        max-height: 40px;
    }
}

/* ===== SOCIAL MENU MIN WIDTH 900 PX END ==== */

/* ===== SOCIAL MEDIA MENU END ==== */

.header {

}
/* logo */

.logo-header {
        width: 27.5%;
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        height: 70px;
        align-items: center;
        margin-left: 2.5%;
        
}

.logo-header img {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        height: 60px;
        width: 60px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 899px){
.logo-header {
        width: 27.5%;
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        height: 70px;
        align-items: center;
        margin-left: 2.5%;
        
}

.logo-header img {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        height: 50px;
        width: 50px;
}
}

/* nav */

/* ===== FULLSCREEN NAVIGATION MENU START ==== */

/* ==== WORDPRESS PRIMARY MENU ABOVE 769 PX START ==== */

.site-nav {
    width: 50%;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    font-size: 2.4rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    padding-right: 2.5%;
    
        
}

.site-nav ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    list-style: none;
    align-items: center;
    
    
}

.site-nav ul:before, .site-nav ul:after { content: ""; display: table; }
.site-nav ul:after { clear: both; }
.site-nav ul { *zoom: 1; }

.site-nav ul li  {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #949494;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding-left: 1.6rem;
    
    
}
.site-nav ul li a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #949494;
    text-decoration: none;
    
    
}
.site-nav ul li a:hover {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #555555;
    text-decoration: none;
    
}
li.current-menu-item a {
    color: #555555 !important;
    text-decoration: none;
    
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 899px){
    
    .site-nav {
        font-size: 2rem;
        padding-right: 3.5%;
    }
    
}

/* ==== WORDPRESS PRIMARY MENU ABOVE 769 PX END ==== */

/* ===== RESPOSIVE NAV START ==== */
/* ===== RESPOSIVE NAV START ==== */
/* ===== RESPOSIVE NAV START ==== */
/* ===== RESPOSIVE NAV START ==== */

/* ---- DONT SHOW RESPONSIVE IN FULL SCREEN ---- */


@media only screen and (min-width: 769px) {
.responsive-nav {
    display: none;
    }
    
.responsive-nav ul {
    display: none;
    }
    
.responsive-nav li {
    display: none;
    }

    }
/* ---- DONT SHOW RESPONSIVE IN FULL SCREEN END ---- */    
 
/* ===== RESPONSIVE NAV MOBILE MEDIA QUERY @ MIN-MAX 451-768 PX ==== */
    
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    
    .site-nav {
        display: none;
    }
    
 
    .responsive-nav {
        float:right;
        width: 50vw;
        margin: auto;
        clear: right;
        position: fixed;
        top: 70px;
        right: 0;
        border-left: 1px solid #eee;
        background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
        min-height: 100vh;
        transform: translateX(100%);
        transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
        
    }
    
    .responsive-nav-view {
        float:right;
        width: 50vw;
        margin: auto;
        clear: right;
        position: fixed;
        top: 70px;
        right: 0;
        border-left: 1px solid #eee;
        background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
        min-height: 100vh;
        transform: translateX(0);
        transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
        
    }
    
    .responsive-nav ul {
        display: block;
        padding-left: 0px !important;
        margin: 0 !important;
        font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
        font-size: 2rem;
        list-style: none;
                
   
    }
    
    .responsive-nav li {
        display: block;
        padding: 0;
        position: relative;    
    }
    
    .responsive-nav a:hover {
        color: #555555;
    }
    
    .responsive-nav li:first-child {
        display: block;
        padding-top: 10px;
        position: relative;
        
    }
    
    .responsive-nav a {
        display: block;
        padding: 0;
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #949494;
        position: relative;   
    }
}



@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    
    .responsive-hide {
        width: 47.5%;
        display: flex;
        flex-flow: row;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        justify-content: flex-end;
        padding-right: 2.5%;
    }
    
    .toggle-nav {
        display: flex;
        flex-flow: row;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        align-items: center;
        height: 70px;
        
        
    }
    
    #hamburger {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        width: 36px;
        height: 20px;
        color: #949494;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg);
        -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
        -o-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
        transition: .5s ease-in-out;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    #hamburger span {
        color: #949494;
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        height: 2px;
        width: 100%;
        background: #949494;
        border-radius: 2px;
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg);
        -webkit-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
        -o-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
        transition: .25s ease-in-out;
    }
    
    #hamburger span:nth-child(1) {
        top: 0px;
    }

    #hamburger span:nth-child(2) {
        top: 8px;
    }

    #hamburger span:nth-child(3) {
        top: 16px;
    }
    
    #hamburger.open span:nth-child(1) {
        top: 8px;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(135deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(135deg);
        transform: rotate(135deg);
    }

    #hamburger.open span:nth-child(2) {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transition: 0.25s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: 0.25s ease-in-out;
        -o-transition: 0.25s ease-in-out;
        transition: 0.25s ease-in-out;    
    }

    #hamburger.open span:nth-child(3) {
        top: 8px;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(-135deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(-135deg);
        transform: rotate(-135deg);
    }
    
    #hamburger:hover {
        cursor: pointer;
        color: #555555;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- wrapper -->
<div class="container">

  <!-- header -->
  <header class="wrapper">

    <div class="logo-header">
      <img src="http://testsiteclash.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/luke-logo-layers-copy.png">
    </div>

    <!-- responsive nav -->
    <div class="responsive-hide">
      <div class="toggle-nav">
        <div id="hamburger">
          <span></span>
          <span></span>
          <span></span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <nav id="responsive-nav">
        <ul id="responsive-nav" class="responsive-nav">
          <li id="menu-item-32" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-home current-menu-item page_item page-item-5 current_page_item menu-item-32"><a href="http://testsiteclash.co.uk/">Home</a></li>
          <li id="menu-item-31" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-31"><a href="http://testsiteclash.co.uk/about">About</a></li>
          <li id="menu-item-30" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-30"><a href="http://testsiteclash.co.uk/gallery">Gallery</a></li>
          <li id="menu-item-29" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-29"><a href="http://testsiteclash.co.uk/contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
    <!-- responsive nav -->

    <!-- nav -->
    <nav class="site-nav">
      <ul>
        <li id="menu-item-9" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-9"><a href="http://testsiteclash.co.uk/">Home</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-10" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-10"><a href="http://testsiteclash.co.uk/about">About</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-47" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-47"><a href="http://testsiteclash.co.uk/blog">Blog</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-18" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-18"><a href="http://testsiteclash.co.uk/contact">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <!-- /nav -->


    <div class="socials">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#"><img src="http://testsiteclash.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/facebook-icon.png" id="facebook" onmouseover="newPicture()" onmouseout="oldPicture()" /></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#"><img src="http://testsiteclash.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/insta-icon.png" id="instagram" onmouseover="newPicture1()" onmouseout="oldPicture1()" /></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#"><img src="http://testsiteclash.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/twitter-icon.png" id="twitter" onmouseover="newPicture2()" onmouseout="oldPicture2()" /></a>
        </li>
        <!--<li><a href="#"><img src="http://testsiteclash.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/pinterest-icon.png" id="pinterest" onmouseover="newPicture3()" onmouseout="oldPicture3()"/></a></li>-->
      </ul>
    </div>



  </header>
  <!-- /header -->
```

Comment: Please click the `<>` button in the editor and create a [mcve] without any php - it is not a php issue

Comment: Please remove your PHP and replace it with the output it generates, thank you.

Comment: i am using the wordpress html5 blank theme if that helps?

Comment: Why not just `$('#hamburger').on("click",function() {
           $('.responsive-nav').toggleClass('responsive-nav-view');
       });`

Comment: are you saying to remove the php section form this post?

Comment: @PaulStephenDavis we are saying to replace the PHP with the HTML that the PHP generates. Then create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For example, we don't know exactly what `wp_nav_menu()` generates, which could be valuable in providing an answer to your question.

Comment: the php code is irrelevant (as the wordpress tag). your question is about HTML+CSS+JS.

Comment: okay sorry new to all this relatively!! thanks

Comment: Have @hungerstar done a snippet, is this what you meant?

Comment: @PaulStephenDavis while providing a **working** [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (snippet) is always desirable, currently we would like the HTML the PHP generates. I'm not sure how to phrase it any simpler than that. Your PHP creates HTML. We want the HTML it makes.

Comment: so would you get that using view source?

Comment: @hungerstar I have copied into the snippet the view source information is that what you need?

Comment: Yes, that's what I would do. And only provide the relevant parts to create a [working Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable ](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Not the whole page. Make sure you include any required scripts and CSS.

Comment: haha too late will go back and copy out the header section!

Comment: @hungerstar what would you deem as relevent just the header section? or just the responsive nav output?

Comment: @hungerstar have you seen my updated snippet?

Comment: @PaulStephenDavis I have. I added jQuery to the snippet. Your social icons have inline event handlers on them. I would either remove those so they don't produce errors or include the JS for them. Ultimately they're probably not the issue but you would want to rectify the error they produce so the rest of the JS runs. Then people can modify the code as needed and provide solutions. Remember, it's all about providing as minimal and straight forward example of your problem as possible. A lot of times it doesn't even have to be actual code as long as it replicates the issue properly.

Comment: @PaulStephenDavis did you update your CSS and things stopped working? That is, besides making it `flexbox`. Did you make other changes as well?

Comment: have removed inline styles now yes

Comment: @PaulStephenDavis Sorry I wasn't clear in my last question. Besides making it `flexbox` did you make other CSS changes as well? Like changing the positioning or floats?

Comment: yes i did, as when i put the old css in it did not line up, should i revert to the original css?

Comment: Give it a try.I think that's more the culprit than your JS. Especially if the HTML has not changed and you have not changed CSS ID and Classes that you've used. I'm playing with your HTML/CSS right now. I'll see what I can do. One quick question. Are you calling `wp_nav_menu()` twice to create each menu? If so, that may not be necessary to have two menus, depending on layout/functionality requirements of course.

Comment: one is being called via wp_nav_menu and the other is a custom function called html5blank_nav which seems to be an array set on wp_nav_menu

Comment: @hungerstar I just dont get it? it is kind of working in the snippet but not at all on chrome in live site version?

Comment: Okay, I see the reason for two menus now. Just to clarify, when you click the hamburger icon the menu should slide in under the header vs sliding everything over?

Comment: yes it displays from the bottom of the header wrapper down to the beginning of the footer, hence using 100VH

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible solution, not that I have modified what you had quite a bit and is not 100% perfect. Hopefully it'll get you in the right direction.

```js
$( document ).ready( function () {

  var $nav = $( '.site-nav' ),
      $ham = $( '#hamburger' );

  $ham.on( 'click', function () {
  
    $ham.toggleClass( 'open' );
    $nav.toggleClass( 'reveal' );
    
  } );
  
} );
```

```css
*,
*:after,
*:before {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  font-smoothing: antialiased;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}

html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font: 300 11px/1.4 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #444;
}

/* Clearfix */

.clear:before,
.clear:after {
  content: ' ';
  display: table;
}

.clear:after {
  clear: both;
}

.clear {
  *zoom: 1;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

ul,
li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

/* Flexbox Utilities */
.flex-center {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

@media ( min-width: 900px ) {
  .flex-lg-center {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
  }
}

/* Mobile => 899px */
header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  height: 70px;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #eee;
}

/* 900px plus */
@media (min-width: 900px) {
  header {
    height: 80px;
  }
}

/* Mobile => 899px */
.socials {
  border-left: 2px solid #eee;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.socials li {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.socials li img {
  max-height: 35px;
}


/* 900px plus */
@media ( min-width: 900px ) {
  .socials li img {
    max-height: 40px;
  }
}


/* Mobile => 899px */
.logo-header {
  flex-grow: 1;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.logo-header img {
  width: 50px;
}


/* 900px plus */
@media ( min-width: 900px) {
  .logo-header img {
    width: 60px;
  }
}

/* Navigation */
.site-nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 70px;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: block;
  font-size: 2.4rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  transform: translateX( 100% );
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.site-nav.reveal {
  transform: translateX( 0 );
}
.site-nav ul {
  display: block;
  margin: 20px
}
.site-nav li {
  margin-right: 20px;
}
.site-nav ul li a {
  color: #949494;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.site-nav ul li a:hover {
  color: #555555;
}

@media ( min-width: 900px ) {
  .site-nav {
    position: relative;
    top: initial;
    right: initial;
    bottom: initial;
    display: flex;
    background-color: transparent;
    transform: translateX( 0 );
  }
  .site-nav ul {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
  }
}

#hamburger {
  align-self: center;
  width: 36px;
  height: 22px;
  margin: 0 20px;
  color: #949494;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#hamburger div {
  color: #949494;
  position: relative;
  height: 2px;
  background: #949494;
  border-radius: 2px;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  -webkit-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  transition: .25s ease-in-out;
}

#hamburger div:nth-child(1) {
  top: 0px;
}

#hamburger div:nth-child(2) {
  top: 8px;
}

#hamburger div:nth-child(3) {
  top: 16px;
}

#hamburger.open div:nth-child(1) {
  top: 8px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(135deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(135deg);
  transform: rotate(135deg);
}

#hamburger.open div:nth-child(2) {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: 0.25s ease-in-out;
  transition: 0.25s ease-in-out;
}

#hamburger.open div:nth-child(3) {
  top: 8px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
}

#hamburger:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #555555;
}

@media ( min-width: 900px) {
  #hamburger {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- header -->
<header class="wrapper">

  <div class="logo-header flex-center">
    <img src="http://testsiteclash.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/luke-logo-layers-copy.png">
  </div>

  <div id="hamburger">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
  
  <nav class="site-nav flex-center">
    <ul class="flex-lg-center">
      <li id="menu-item-9" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-9"><a href="http://testsiteclash.co.uk/">Home</a></li>
      <li id="menu-item-10" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-10"><a href="http://testsiteclash.co.uk/about">About</a></li>
      <li id="menu-item-47" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-47"><a href="http://testsiteclash.co.uk/blog">Blog</a></li>
      <li id="menu-item-18" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-18"><a href="http://testsiteclash.co.uk/contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <!-- /nav -->

  <div class="socials flex-center">
    <ul class="flex-center">
      <li>
        <a href="#"><img src="http://testsiteclash.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/facebook-icon.png" id="facebook"></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#"><img src="http://testsiteclash.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/insta-icon.png" id="instagram"></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#"><img src="http://testsiteclash.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/twitter-icon.png" id="twitter"></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</header>
<!-- /header -->
```

I noticed a lot of redundant properties being applied in your CSS.

For example, you had:

```
.logo-header img {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
}

@media only screen and ( max-width: 899px ) {

  .logo-header img {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
  }

}
```

When it could be:

```
.logo-header img {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
}

@media only screen and ( max-width: 899px ) {

  .logo-header img {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
  }

}
```

No need to redefine `display` and `flex-wrap` as it's already defined for `.logo-header img` at any screen size.

You'll notice I also switched up how you were using media queries to a mobile first approach, you were doing desktop first:

```
.logo-header img {
  /* This was applied at 900px plus */
}

@media only screen and ( max-width: 899px ) {

  .logo-header img {
    /* This was applied at 0 to 899px */
  }

}
```

The first few responsive sites I built I did it this way, then I swapped it up to how I did it in the example and you'll see it's much more natural once you've done it a couple times. Mobile first would be like this:

```
.logo-header img {
  /* This was applied at 0 to 899px */
}

@media only screen and ( min-width: 900px ) {

  .logo-header img {
    /* This was applied at 900px plus */
  }

}
```

Notice how just reading it is more natural? Going from smaller to bigger.

I removed a few other irrelevant CSS too, i.e. for `.wrapper` you don't need to remove padding for an element that doesn't have any initially or set a `z-index` when you're not positioning it.

Comment: thanks man, absolute star, hopefully it teaches me as much as it should, really new to all this but find code very interesting in its behaviour. Thanks again